# My CSS drop down menu has a space between it and the right border. How do I remove it?

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, border

I created a css drop down menu and i am finishing it up with a border. When i added the left and bottom border everything was fine. Once i added the right border it put a gap between the right border and the drop down menu. Is there anyway to fix this?
Here is a photo http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/563034_641717089180441_1749213926_n.jpg

The HTML I Used:

```
<nav id="main_nav" class="fluid">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Show Services</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Audio</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Lighting</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Power</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Special Effects</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Staging/Trussing</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Systems Integration</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Corporate and Commercial</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Digital Signage</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">IP Based Systems</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
           <ul>
             <li><a href="#">Concrets</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Installations</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Parties</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Product Launch</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Trade Shows</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Our Company</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

The CSS I Used:

```
#main_nav {
}
#main_nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
#main_nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
#main_nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 0%;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: allerta;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    border-left: 0.1em solid #999999;
    border-bottom: 0.1em solid #999999;
    border-right: 0.1em solid #999999;
}
#main_nav a:hover, #main_nav a:active, #main_nav a:focus, #main_nav a.thispage {
    background-color: #666666;
    color: #0099FF;
    width: 100%;
}
#main_nav ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#main_nav ul li ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
#main_nav ul li ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-left: 0%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0%;
    float: left;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: allerta;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#main_nav ul li:hover ul, #main_nav ul li:active ul, #main_nav ul li:focus ul, #main_nav ul li.thispage ul {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of menus with the unwanted space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your code and have made some changes. Also took the liberty of creating a JS Fiddle example for you. I haven't changed any HTML, only the CSS.

[See JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tW2tR/5/)

```
    html {
        font: 100%/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
    }
/* Common (Shared) Properties */
    #main_nav, ul, li, a {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #main_nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
    #main_nav li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 20%;
        background: #4d4d4d;
    }
    #main_nav a {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1em;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border-top: none;
    }
    #main_nav a:hover,
    #main_nav a:active, 
    #main_nav a:focus, 
    #main_nav a.thispage {
        background: #666;
        color: #FFF;
    }
/* Controls Dropdown */
    #main_nav ul li ul {
        visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        top: auto; /* Updated position to 'auto' and removed margin-top: 100% */
        left: 0;
    }
    #main_nav ul ul li {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #main_nav ul li:hover ul, 
    #main_nav ul li:active ul, 
    #main_nav ul li:focus ul, 
    #main_nav ul li.thispage ul {
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Should really make it clear what you changed and why, not just return the edited code

Comment: I probably should have made it more clear, Chris, but at the time I was extremely busy. I reasoned that some help was better than none at all.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote CSS which hopefully will be helpful to learn from as it is much simpler to understand as well as it fixes your problem.

Problem was that the sub menu items were with 100% width + 1px border on each side which is over 100% so it was overflowing.

Here is the link to JS Fiddle example with fix: http://jsfiddle.net/MartinTale/69gDQ/3/

Here is the new css:

```
#main_nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main_nav ul {
    width: 100%;
}

#main_nav li {  
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#main_nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%; 
}

#main_nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

#main_nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

#main_nav a {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 1px solid #999999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999999;
}

#main_nav ul li ul a {
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
}

#main_nav a:hover,
#main_nav a:active, 
#main_nav a:focus, 
#main_nav a.thispage {
    background: #666;
    color: #09F;
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but this did not help. if you look at the menu again, the border to the right of the buttons of the navigation menu have a little space between it and the border.

Comment: Fixed that too now, see the new CSS. However before there was a much bigger problem and now everything should be fixed. Good luck with the project. ;)

Comment: http://sphotos-b.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/563034_641717089180441_1749213926_n.jpg here is a picture of my problem

Comment: Thank you so much there is just one more problem. The drop down menu pushes the moves my content.

Comment: You should make a new question for it as it is completely different problem you need to figure out. ;)